# Program stops working after read, while return value is correct

Tags: c, tcp

So I have a client-server C program based on TCP protocol. First, server sends the client number of bytes to read (4 bytes (string length) and 2 bytes for code) and that works fine, but than I send a string of said lengt and client stops working properly.

Server code:

```
// char *array = malloc(20000);
// ....
if (write(msg_sock, &filesSendHeader, sizeof(struct AllFiles)) != sizeof(struct AllFiles))
   syserr("partial / failed write");

if (write(msg_sock, array, howMany + 1) != howMany + 1)
   syserr("partial / failed write");
```

msg_sock is a socket for received from accept function.

array - array of chars of size 20000,

howMany + 1 - length of string (including 0 character)

filesSendHeader is an instance of struct AllFiles and holds one 4 byte and 2 byte number

Client code:

```
  // char *array = malloc(20000);
  // ....
  //For reading first struct
  prev_len = 0;
  while (prev_len < sizeof(struct AllFiles)) {
    received = read(sock, ((char*)&file_info) + prev_len, sizeof(struct AllFiles) - prev_len);
    if (received < 0)
      syserr("reading from server socket");
    prev_len += received;
  }

  // Printing struct AllFiles fields and converting them with ntoh...
  // Then reading a string
  uint32_t to_read = ntohl(file_info.value);
  printf("Bytes read:%ld\n", read(sock, array, to_read));
  printf("Hey");
```

sock - socket, client connects to server through (from getaddrinfo)

file_info - instance of struct AllFiles

The server code after writing to socket executes normally. Client print correct number of bytes read, but than it stops working (the program runs but nothing after second to last instruction is printed out). "HEY" is not printed out.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I tried running the program with valgrind, but gave away no memory issues. 
I also did `file_info.value = ntohl(file_info.value);` in client part before sending string length, but as I said struct AllFiles is received properly (i printed it out).

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to step through the receiver?

Comment: And what is `array` (in the receiver)? Is the "array" large enough?

Comment: What is an `AllFiles`? How is it defined?

Comment: By the way, when you send, you don't seem to be doing `htonl` on the `value` member of the structure? Are you doing it in the parts of the code you don't show us? Can you please try to create a [mcve] of both programs to show us?

Comment: Yes it is exacly the same (20000) and I am only sending 15 bytes.

Comment: Is `filesSendHeader.value == htonl(howMany + 1)` true in the sender? Do the `write`s send  the full amount (not partial)?

Comment: Yes, it does otherwise server would do exit(0)

Comment: Please show the lines in your code where you ensure that `filesSendHeader.value` has the same value as `htonl(howMany + 1)`.

Comment: Does `struct AllFiles` have the same size and the same offset of each member on both server and client, and does it contain any padding?

Comment: Tried `printf("Hey\n");` instead of `printf("Hey");`?  `stdout` is line buffered.